# django How do I print functions as they are called?

Tags: django

It's the best way I've found so far.

https://pypi.org/project/Autologging/

```
from autologging import traced
@traced
class SocialAccountAdapter(DefaultSocialAccountAdapter):
    def pre_social_login(self, request, sociallogin):
        user = sociallogin.user
        print(user.email)
        raise Exception('test')
```

However, this method only print the decorated class.

Is there any way to print all the connected subclass functions when they are called?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not related but the visualisation of a program execution can be done with this tool:

https://pythontutor.com/